# Filter/Extract a text from excel sheet having similar values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have data in the cell in this format saved in A column in Excel.

```
[Amber,Maria,Marian,Mar]

[Maria]

[Marian,Amber,Maria]

[Maria,Marian]
```

I want a filter for Maria and Marian.

How can I use some regex formula filtering Maria and Marian separately?

I am using pivot filters and want to use a custom formula there.

`contain(A1,"Maria")` will return Maria and Marian both.

Comment: Can you provide expected result for given sample data? You mention *contain(A1,"Maria") will return Maria and Marian both* is that good/bad, why?

Comment: Might this be what you're looking for: `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maria,",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",","))),"Maria",""),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Marian,",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",","))),"Marian",""))`

Comment: Currently i just need to filter Maria but it shows marian and maria both

Comment: What do you mean by filter. You mean show if it's there? Also, your example all has Maria in it, not a sample co training Marian and not Maria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maria,",SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"]",",")))` shows `TRUE` if `Maria` is found and false if it would only be `Marian`, not `Maria`.
[image]

Comment: Nice solution, the first version was more complicated

Comment: Yes, I first understood he wanted to have both Maria and Marian based on *I want a filter for Maria and Marian.* But out of his comment I understood he ment something else. Also the term Filter is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets and Excel are two different apps. Benefits of GS is indeed, as you mentioned in your question, the use of regular expressions. Reading your question there are two possibilities that pop into mind:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1:A5,"Maria\b"))
```

Formula in `C1`:

```
=QUERY(A:A,"where A matches '.*Maria\b.*'")
```